# Visual Studio 2015 has problems communicating using VISA Libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visa

I'm having problems with the VISA-Com Libraries to communicate with a Keysight (N6700B) power supply.

I have some C# code I am compiling in Visual Studio 2015, and it does not work. However, if I compile the same code in Visual Studio 2012, then it works.

Basically I am just doing simple communication with the device:

```
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;
//...
string address = "USB0::2391::2311::MY54002380::0::INSTR";
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();
FormattedIO488 myDmm = (IMessage)rm.Open(address , AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 2000, "");
myDmm.WriteString("*RST"); // reset the device
myDmm.WriteString("*IDN?"); // request the IDN string;
string IDN = myDmm.ReadString(); // This is where it fails, returning: "VI_ERROR_TMO: A timeout occurred"
```

Also, the power supply has an error state of: "Error -420, Query UNTERMINATED"

The code does not work with VS2015, but it DOES work with VS2012. 
(In VS2012 I get no errors at all.)

I have tried downloading the latest drivers from KeySight, and it still does not work ([www.keysight.com/find/iosuitedownload](http://www.keysight.com/find/iosuitedownload)).

Does anyone have any idea why it would be breaking with VS2015 but work with VS2012?

I've looked up "Quere Unterminated" and some say that it could be a missing Termination character "\n". I've tried adding the "\n" to both writeStrings, and it still fails.

---

EDIT: I have also now tried using (in various places):

```
myDmm.IO.TerminationCharacterEnabled = true; // and = false 

myDmm.FlushWrite(); // also tried passing in "true" (default is 'false')
```

I also tried adding the:

```
myDmm.IO.TerminationCharacter
```

to the WriteStrings.

Comment: Which .Net version are you using? May be when you did the Solution conversion, It also changed the .NET Framework version to the last version. You should take a look at this project and change the version manually to the compatibly one with the Visa Framework

Comment: im using .Net 4.5 in both VS2012 and VS2015. But i'll try different versions. (i was using the same Visa Framework as well, though now i updated to the latest Visa)

Comment: Does the error occur executing the code inside Visual Studio or running the compiled executable outside of Visual Studio ?

Comment: both.
The ".exe" compiled by VS2015 does not work, the ".exe" compiled by VS2012 works fine.

Comment: Have you verified the "Bitness" of the generated assemblies are the same (x86, x64, ANY_CPU)?

Comment: Yes, they are all "ANY_CPU"

Comment: Did you mean "\n" when you put "/n" ? One generates a control character, the other does not.

Comment: yes, i did "\n", also i tried to use their: "myDmm.IO.TerminationCharacter"

See edit above.

Comment: I would suggest at this point, looking at the generated IL in the assembly. If the generated IL is exactly the same, then the problem is probably external to the assembly (perhapse a library reference issue). If the IL is different that may give you a direction on how to modify the code to work with both version of VS.

Comment: ill look into that, for now i've sent Emails to Keysight to see if they have any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://download.ni.com/support/softlib//visa/NI-VISA/15.0/Windows/readme.html

### Microsoft Visual Studio Support

The following table lists the programming languages and Microsoft Visual Studio versions supported by this version of NI-VISA.

Earlier versions of NI-VISA support other application software and language versions. For more information on Visual Studio compatibility with earlier versions of VISA, refer to ni.com/info and enter the info code NETlegacydrivers. To find and download an earlier version of a driver, refer to ni.com/downloads.

> ## Visual Studio Versions Support by NI-VISA:
>
> Visual C++ MFC1  --------------   2008
>
> Framework 3.5 Languages (Visual C# and Visual Basic .NET) -- 2008
>
> .NET Framework 4.0 Languages (Visual C# and Visual Basic .NET)--  2010
>
> .NET Framework 4.5 Languages (Visual C# and Visual Basic .NET)--     2012

So apparently the drivers don't work with VS2015... (not sure how a newer version doesn't work.. but okay)

*EDIT, FOUND ANSWER*

Someone from NI-VISTA told me to just add "true" as a second parameter:

```
myDmm.WriteString("*RST",true); // reset the device
myDmm.WriteString("*IDN?",true); // request the IDN string;
string IDN = myDmm.ReadString(); // now it works.
```

I'm not sure why "true" wasn't needed in 2012, and why it is needed in 2015... oh well.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm: the method WriteString() (but not only this) needs the bool parameter flushAndEND = true (default value = false) in order to complete the command. Without it, the instrument can't parse the instruction. If you send multiple commands, the instrument can't separate and identify them.

I suggest you to use the Keysight IO monitor for sniffing the communication between your instruments and you controller (PC?) . It's an utility of the IO Libraries Suite (v17.1).

For details, see the attached IFormattedIO488 interface definition, belonging to the reference Ivi.Visa.Interop.

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace Ivi.Visa.Interop
    {
            [...]
      public interface IFormattedIO488
      {
        [DispId(1610678274)]
        bool InstrumentBigEndian { get; set; }
        [DispId(1610678272)]
        IMessage IO { get; set; }

        void FlushRead();
        void FlushWrite(bool sendEND = false);
        dynamic ReadIEEEBlock(IEEEBinaryType type, bool seekToBlock = false, bool flushToEND = false);
        dynamic ReadList(IEEEASCIIType type = IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any, string listSeperator = ",;");
        dynamic ReadNumber(IEEEASCIIType type = IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any, bool flushToEND = false);
        string ReadString();
        void SetBufferSize(BufferMask mask, int size);
        void WriteIEEEBlock(string Command, object data, bool flushAndEND = false);
        void WriteList(ref object data, IEEEASCIIType type = IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any, string listSeperator = ",", bool flushAndEND = false);
        void WriteNumber(object data, IEEEASCIIType type = IEEEASCIIType.ASCIIType_Any, bool flushAndEND = false);
        void WriteString(string data, bool flushAndEND = false);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the ReadBytes method? This method reads a fixed amount of bytes from the device. The error you've encountered most probably occurs because the the visa driver tries to read data until a termination character, which you never explicitly set, is received.

Try setting the TerminationCharacter Property to either \n or \r (depending on the instrument) and it should work. Furthermore, you might want to add it to the commands you send as well so the instrument won't bother you with this error (-420) anymore.