# VB.net GPIB Termination character problem

Tags: vb.net, gpib

This is my first question here.
I have a problem with the termination character when sending a message on the GPIB
Default character is line feed and my instrument needs a carriage return.

I´v tried to change it but when I sniffing at the bus it is still line feed.
Anyone knows what I´m doing wrong?

EDIT:
As I understand instrEprobe.IO.TerminationCharacter only affects the receiving message from instrument but I need to send message with carrage return and not line feed

BR
Niklas

```
Public Function InitEprobe(ByVal strGpib As String, ByVal Type As String)
        ioMgr = New Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager
        instrEprobe = New Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488
        Try
                    Dim Out As String = ""
                    instrEprobe.IO = ioMgr.Open("GPIB0::" & strGpib) 'set GPIBport
                    instrEprobe.IO.TerminationCharacter = 13    ' set termination character
                    instrEprobe.IO.TerminationCharacterEnabled = True
                    instrEprobe.WriteString("I") 'Send command to instrument
                    Wait(500)
                    Out = instrEprobe.ReadString 'Read command from instrument
                    Return Out
                
        Catch exp As Exception
            Return exp.ToString
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Is `instrEprobe.IO.TerminationCharacter` supposed to be an integer, or a char or string?

Comment: It shall be an integer. I can in debug mode see that the varible is set to 13, but still line feed when using N/I io trace

Comment: This looks like a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/32120946/832052

Comment: Unfortaintly, I dont find a solution in that issue